# Angular directives: communicating values to controller with ampersand methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to wrap my head around Angular directives with isolated scope and communicating with controllers.

What i'm trying to create is a simple reusable search component. This component has a model value (the query) and should have some way to indicate to the controller that the search button is clicked.

The `index.html` looks like this:

```
<searchbox
    ng-model="query"
    on-search="search()"
></searchbox>

<p>Current search query: {{query}}</p>
```

The `<searchbox>` directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('searchbox', function() {
    return {
        link : function(scope) {
            scope.submit = function() {
                console.log('Trying to return the query ' + scope.q);
                scope.onSearch(scope.q);
            }
        },
        replace : true,
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {
            'ngModel' : '=q',
            'onSearch' : '&'
        },
        template : ''.concat(
            '<form><input ng-model="q" type="text" />',
            '<input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="submit()" />',
            '</form>'
        )
    };
});
```

And the main controller looks like this:

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.search = function(query) {
        alert('You searched for ' + query);
        alert('Search value: ' + $scope.query);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately the query does not appear in the controller, both as a result of the `search` callback, and as a `$scope` propery.

I've Google around a bit, but most of the answers seem to use some variation of `$scope.$eval`, or directly call the controller, which seems a bit like a kludge.

A Codepen with the example above is available here: http://codepen.io/hay/pen/Avwjz

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues here:

The scope definition has to be

```
'q' : '=ngModel',
```

The left side is the name you want to use internally (your template uses `q`), the right side is the name of the attribute.

The HTML has to be

```
on-search="search(query)"
```

with your `submit` handler being

```
...
scope.onSearch();
```

`&` means that the expression is evaluated as is. If the expression is just `search()`, then `search` is **always** called without any parameter, no matter what.

Comment: Thanks! Silly that i just mixed up the key and value properties in the `scope` object.